# 2-color diagonal gradient with stripes on one color in CSS

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

Is it possible to create a two-color diagonal gradient (white and black) with blue stripes on the black side? There's no problem in creating black and white diagonal gradient but the stripes are a little challenge. I need to achieve effect like on the attached image (to the end of the screen). [image: two-color gradient with stripes]

Also, can I set width of the black and blue stripes?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post the code you use, as I can't see why we need to setup that for you to suggest a slution